# I am getting a database error. wpyg_options table is not okay

Tags: php, wordpress

I get 'Error establishing a database connection' when I pull my Wordpress webiste up.  If I try and access wp-admin I get the following message, 'One or more database tables are unavailable.  The database may need to be repaired'.  When I click on 'repaired' and then 'Repair Database', it lists tables but the only one that says Not Okay is wpyg_options table.

This is the entire message...
The wpyg_options table is not okay. It is reporting the following error: Table 'dbv0jdkljak2g3.wpyg_options' doesn't exist. WordPress will attempt to repair this table…
Failed to repair the wpyg_options table. Error: Table 'dbv0jdkljak2g3.wpyg_options' doesn't exist.

I am not a programmer so I'm having a hard time figuring out what is the problem.  I tried googling this but cannot locate the same error message.  Any suggestions will be appreciated.

I tried disabling all plugins but that had no affect.

Comment: This site is for programmers to help each other (as per the [tour] ... see also [ask]). If you're a non-programmer with what sounds like a WordPress configuration problem (rather than a programming question) you'd probably be better to ask on the specific WordPress Stackexchange site - but please read _their_ tour and related guidance before posting, to ensure your question stays on-topic